# How to return part of a string

Tags: python, string

So I have a string `str = 'yadayada; borg and ; 12for;scion$march.car; end`

The key character I'm searching for is `$` so how do I return the partial string `scion$march.car`

I used `string.find(str,'$')` to find the index of `$` within the string.

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.split` and `next`:

```
>>> s = 'yadayada; borg and ; 12for;scion$march.car; end'
>>> next((x for x in s.split(';') if '$' in x), None) #return None if no match was gound
'scion$march.car'
```

**Explanation:**

`s.split(';')` splits the string at `';'` and returns a list, now we iterate over this list and return the first item that contains `'$'`:

```
>>> s.split(';')
['yadayada', ' borg and ', ' 12for', 'scion$march.car', ' end']
```

The above code is roughly equivalent to:

```
def solve(strs):
    for s in strs.split(';'):
        if '$' in s:
            return s
...         
>>> solve(s)
'scion$march.car'
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with next, a more verbose statement might be
`for eachpart in s.split(';'): if '$' in eachpart: print eachpart`

Answer (score 0):

`split()` as above is probably the cleanest way. But you can also do it with `find()` and `rfind()` as below

```
i = s.find('$')
m = s[s.rfind(';', 0, i)+1:s.find(';',i)]
print m
```

Essentially you find the first `';'` after the `'$'`, the first `';'` before it, and extract the substring between them.